# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process on Remote Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, network-programming, file-permissions

`"Directory.Delete"` in the following code is giving an error...

> The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by
>   another process

Any suggestion?

The following code works fine first time. But when executing 2nd time, then it gives error.

```
 public void Method1(){  

           //  NetworkShareAccesser implenting IDispoable
           // e.g: public class NetworkShareAccesser : IDisposable
           using (NetworkShareAccesser.Access(Config.DMS_SERVER_IP, Config.SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME, Config.SERVER_USERNAME, Config.SERVER_PASSWORD))
           {
           try
           {       
                 Directory.Delete(absolutePathServerForService, true);  
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(absolutePathServerForService);
                 Common.CopyFilesRecursively(new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath), new DirectoryInfo(targetPath));
            }
            catch (Exception e) { loggingService.Error(ex); }
    }

    // following method in common class 
    public static void CopyFilesRecursively(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in source.GetDirectories())
                CopyFilesRecursively(directoryInfo, target.CreateSubdirectory(directoryInfo.Name));
             foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in source.GetFiles())
                  fileInfo.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fileInfo.Name),true);                   
            }
```

Comment: Its  may be because of FileInfo.CopyTo see this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.copyto(v=vs.71).aspx . you have to  Create the file and clean up handles.

Comment: What do you mean by 2nd time? Which of the two methods causes the error?